# error when downloading the gensim package in python

Tags: python, gensim

I have been trying to install the gensim package in python using pip, using the `pip.main(['install','gensim'])`. It works and starts downloading, but then I get the following error:

[image: error in shell]

```
THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
gensim from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/f2/c2f2c87ed72483fce010fbfea1a3adbd168c0f0dafc878cbfb5a76381b03/gensim-3.4.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#sha256=7bafe3f2fd49738942ef04396cb1e50a38283fe02203e5d4c66588daa01fb87c:
    Expected sha256 7bafe3f2fd49738942ef04396cb1e50a38283fe02203e5d4c66588daa01fb87c
         Got        728e9e79db209cfb0699c815c30a6169cefa61f46ef3471937100e4173fdbb3d
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please copy paste your error as text so it may be indexed by future searchers.

Comment: wow! Thank you, Andy! I wasn't allowed to add attachments

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the package pip is trying to download and install is being modified in transit. You should be able to download, verify, and install the package yourself.

1. Download the package:

   `$ curl -O https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/f2/c2f2c87ed72483fce010fbfea1a3adbd168c0f0dafc878cbfb5a76381b03/gensim-3.4.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl`
2. Calculate the SHA256 sum to ensure the package has not been modifed:

   `$ openssl sha256 gensim-3.4.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl`

The output should be `7bafe3f2fd49738942ef04396cb1e50a38283fe02203e5d4c66588daa01fb87c` (according to https://pypi.org/project/gensim/#files)

3. Install the package:

   `$ pip install gensim-3.4.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl`

Comment: Thank you Nathan. Steps one and two works perfectly. when i type pip install gensim.whl in my cmd, i get this:gensim.whl is not a valid wheel filename.

Comment: My mistake, pip appears to require that you use the original filename. I've updated my answer to use the original instead of renaming it to `gensim.whl`

Comment: Alright.The thing is I have anaconda installed, but I have no idea how to use the packages from there. When I did what you posted I get that the requirement satisfied, but the package is in anaconda. Is there a way where I download the package directly in python?      <Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.7->boto3->smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim==3.4.0) (0.14)>

Comment: Some googling turned up https://deparkes.co.uk/2015/02/04/anaconda-whl-install/ which suggests you can use pip through the Anaconda Command Prompt.

Comment: "It seems like the package pip is trying to download and install is being modified in transit. " Interesting. Any idea how this can happen without an attack? I'd be interested in a diff

Comment: It could be that there was a network hiccup and only part of the file downloaded. There's a chance that trying again would have succeeded.

Comment: I have been trying for the past two days, but i keep getting the same error

Comment: The anoconda exmpale you have given @Nathan requires a anaconda command prompt, and in mac that doenst exist. Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: is there any other way? @NathanVillaescusa, your method worked but at the last step i am getting this:  Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in ./Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.10->boto3->smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim==3.4.0),, As you can see it is in the anaconda file not python. I need the package to be installed in python, how can I do that from a mac

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve the problem but I found a way to work around this challenge. I started using anaconda directly. I used the navigator to install gensim in my environments, then I used the spyder command prompt to run my codes.

These links are useful:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/

https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos